# How to calculate the helicity of polarized light?

Tags: optics, quantum-optics

At first, I used to think that only circular polarized light has non-zero helicity, linear polarized light has zero helicity, because the linear polarization can be seperated as the superposition of right and left circular polarization which have equal helicity but opposite in sign.

From some articles, I realized I was wrong, but I can not understand why.

Is it my idea wrong? Why can not I calculate the helicity of linear polarization by adding the helicity of two different circular polarization?

And, in experiments, we can obtain different polarized light such as linear and circular polarization by rotating the 1/4 $\lambda$ plate from input of linear polarized light.

There are the formulas about the helicity of polarization, as a function of $\phi$ which is the angle between the optical axis of the $\lambda / 4$ plate and the direction of the initial polarization.
$$P_{lin} = \frac{1}{4} \sin( 4 \phi )$$
$$P'_{lin} = \frac{1 + \cos( 4 \phi )}{4}$$
$$P_{circ} = \sin( 2 \phi )$$
Here, the article says that two Stokes parameters, $P_{lin}$ and $P'_{lin}$, describe the degrees of linear polarization.

My second question is, how to derive the formula? And how to comprehend the reason why linear polarized light also has non-zero helicity?

Comment: Could you please cite the articles you speak of?

Comment: Oh, sorry very much, I have made mistake. I checked the article again, and found the author did not say that linear polarized light has non-zero helicity. So, please ignore my question...

Comment: The article is here.[V V Bel'kov et al 2005 J. Phys.: Condens. Matter 17 3405](http://iopscience.iop.org/0953-8984/17/21/032/) Please check the equations 3~5. Now, I just want to know how to derive them. Sorry again...

Comment: Only the $P_{circ}$ term reflects the helicity of light. The $P_{lin}$ and $P'_{lin}$ are indenpent of helicity. I think I have found the answer which is just my mistake. My last question is how to derive the formula.